# Using Interplot with Felm Model to Plot Interaction Effect

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to graphically model the interaction effect of an `felm` model in R. I am using the `interplot` package to graph the effects (ideally with confidence intervals, as I have seen done with normal `lm` regressions. However, when I code with `felm`, I receive the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘sim’ for signature ‘"felm"’
```

My coding was as simple as

```
reg_test <- felm(data = dataframe, outcome ~  x*x_interaction + controls | country_fe + year_fe)

interplot::interplot(reg_test, var1 = "x", var2 = "x_interaction")
```

Is `interplot` fundamentally incompatable with `felm`, or is there a way I can make the two compatable and graphically plot the interaction effects of my fixed effect regression? Is there something I need to add, or can I convert the `felm` into a format that makes generating the interaction plot work? Alternatively, is there another package than `interplot` that would work with `felm` and allow me to generate the interaction plot with confidence intervals?